# Can you make the Flutter TabBar Slidable between each tab?

Tags: flutter

On iOS native it's possible to have a tab bar that is slidable between each tab horizontally but I can't seem to find a solution to this in flutter. I have the following code within an `AppBar()`

```
bottom: TabBar(
            controller: _tabController,
            //isScrollable: true,
            onTap: onTabTapped,
            unselectedLabelColor: Colors.white,
            labelColor: Colors.white,
            indicator: const UnderlineTabIndicator(
              borderSide: BorderSide(width: 3.0, color: colorTintBlue),
              insets: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 24),
            ),
            labelPadding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10.0),
            labelStyle: TextStyle(
                fontSize: SizeConfig.scaledHeight(1.8),
                color: const Color(0xFF54A3B4),
                fontFamily: fontFamilySourceSans,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.w900,
                letterSpacing: 1.8),
            tabs: const <Widget>[Tab(text: 'HOME'), Tab(text: 'MY TRIPS'), Tab(text: 'BIKE HEALTH')],
          ),
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57985911/sliding-tab-bar-horizontally-in-flutter 
Is this the answer you are looking for?

Comment: No the answer to this is basically what I have already